# Matlab - how to find output values of a table, which belong to input values not included in the table

Tags: matlab, regression

I am given a table with two columns, Pin and Pout. I want to shift all values of Pin by a constant h1 and find the corresponding value of Pout. The problem of this task is that in the table there are not necessarilly corresponding values of Pout belonging to the shifted values of Pin. Therefore, I was trying this code:

```
pol         = polyfit(Pin,Pout,5);
poly        = polyval(pol,transpose(-27:0.0001:2));
Pout_shift  = poly(ismember(Pin + h1,transpose(-27:0.0001:2)));
```

So, I fit a polynomial to my table and I evaluate the polynomial at very closely spaced values. And then I try to find the values of the polynomial which belong to Pin + h1. This, however, doesn't work.

I know, it's probably hard for you to find the error, since you are not given the table. It has values that range from -26 to 1. All values are decimals with up to 2 digits after the dot. So I figured, by decreasing the spacing at which I evaluate the polynomial, I should eventually consider all P_in + h1. But I don't.

Any ideas? Any ideas of doing it completely different maybe?

Comment: It's hard to said without knowing what represent `Pin` and `Pout`. Which factors can explain the difference between Pin and Pout ? Are those factors linear or not ? ...

Comment: And by the way why are you thinking that a polynomial of degree 5 will fit Pout ?